# Make xml tags explicitly close with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, xml

I have a string with xml tags:

```
<strong><em>Some text</em> more text</strong>
```

I need it to look like that:

```
<strong><em>Some text</em></strong> <strong>more text</strong>
```

In other words I need the explicit closing of each tag.

another example:

```
<em>Another <strong>line <u>of text</u> etc.</strong> more text</em>
```

should look like that:

```
<em>Another</em> <em><strong>line</strong></em> <em><strong><u>of text</u></strong></em> <strong>etc.</strong> <em>more text</em>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with javascript or jquery? Do I need a plugin for that?

In the system I'm working on, I'm converting multiple tags into single tags, e.g. `<i><b>` would become `<ib>` and `<u><i><b>` would become `<uib>`. This is necessary for future import into InDesign which only 'understands' straight html elements - `<tag>string</tag>` - it doesn't recognize tags within tags. Therefore I need to convert inner xml tags to a flat structure.

I've tried regex, loops, etc. but it gets too complicated each time and doesn't cover every scenario.

Comment: https://logrocket.com/blog/youre-using-em-wrong/

Comment: This `<em><strong>Some text</em> more text</strong>` looks like invalid html

Comment: use jquery to manipulate dom

Comment: @ArulMani Thanks. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, but... *why*?? I've never seen a situation where such a design would be necessary? (I'm not trying to patronise you; I'm concerned you may be asking an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)).

Comment: in the system I'm working on, I'm converting multiple tags into single tags, e.g. <i><b> would become <ib> and <u><i><b> would become <uib>. This is necessary for future import into InDesign which only 'understands' straight html elements - <tag>string</tag> - it doesn't recognize tags within tags. Therefore I need to convert inner xml tags to a flat structure. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with 3 loops.
First loop splits the original string at tags.

```
var strArr = xml.split (/(<[^<]+?>[^<]+?(?=<))/), newArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++ ) {
    if (strArr [i] != '')
        newArr.push (strArr [i]);
}
```

Second loop adds unclosed tags to every string in order they appear in the original string.

```
for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++ ) {
    if (newArr [i].match (/<[^\/]/)) {
        var tag = newArr [i].match (/<[^\/<]+?>/) [0];
        for (var j = i+1; j < newArr.length; j++ ) {
            if (!newArr [j].match (new RegExp (tag.replace (/</, '</'))) && !newArr [j].match (tag) && !newArr [j].match (/<\//)) {
                var t_str = newArr [j].split (/(<[^<]+?>)/);
                var xml_elem = '';
                for (var k = 2; k < t_str.length; k ++) {
                    xml_elem += t_str [k]
                }
                newArr [j] = t_str [1] + tag + xml_elem;
            } else if (newArr [j].match (new RegExp (tag.replace (/</, '</')))) {
                tag = '';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Third loop adds closing tags to every string in reverse order.

```
for (var i = newArr.length - 1; i > -1 ; i-- ) {
    var comp_str = newArr [i].replace (/<\/[^<]+?>/g, '');
    if (comp_str.match (/<[^<]+?>/)) {
        var reverse_tags = comp_str.match (/<[^<]+?>/g).reverse ().join ('').replace (/</g, '</');
        newArr [i] = comp_str + reverse_tags;
    } else if (comp_str != ''){
        newArr [i] = comp_str;
    }
    if (comp_str.replace (/<[^<]+?>/g, '') == '') {
        newArr.splice (i, 1);
    }
}
```

There you go.